# Django: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm working on my project for a course and I'm totally stuck right now.
Login doesn't work. I using class-based views. When I`m logged in, everything works.The Logout View  works too.
The error is as follows:

```
    NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.1.6
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Location:     /home/aleo/#HOME/.virtualenvs/znajdki/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /home/aleo/#HOME/.virtualenvs/znajdki/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.8.6
```

My files:
**poszukiwania/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'poszukiwania'

urlpatterns=[

    path('<slug:kategoria_slug>/', views.rzeczy_list, name='rzeczy_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:rzecz_slug>/<int:id>', views.rzecz_detail, name='rzecz_detail'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.rzeczy_list, name='rzeczy_list'),
]
```

**znajdki/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('poszukiwania.urls', namespace='poszukiwania'))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'poszukiwania:rzeczy_list'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

**templates/registration/login.html**

```
 {% extends "poszukiwania/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Logowanie{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Logowanie</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>
            Nazwa użytkownika lub hasło są nieprawidłowe.
            Spróbuj ponownie
        </p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Wypełnij aby się zalogować</p>
    {% endif %}
 
    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="{% url 'poszukiwania:login' %}" method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            <p><input type="submit" value="Zaloguj się"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

help me, please

Comment: `LOGIN_URL = 'poszukiwania:login'`

Comment: ok, I have another problem. When I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/login shows me error ''page not found"

Comment: @Aleooo your urls are not well designed (or at least well ordered) the urls `'login/'` would match `'<slug:kategoria_slug>/'` and hence you get the error.

Comment: Yeah :DD there was a wrong order. I put  the path url 'login' at the beginning of the urlpatterns and WORKS!!! Thank you! :D